# private type alias in class scope in header file

Tags: c++, type-alias

I want to use type alias to shorten the long names of
parameters to member-functions within my class.

The parameters can be of type: `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>>`

I want to know, if adding private aliases inside a class in the header file, is safe for a library? Is it a bad practice? then why and what kind of errors can it lead to?
Given that this header will get included by all kinds of libraries and projects.

Here is an example:

```
// A.h. - will get included by other libraries

namespace mylib::module
{
  class A
  {        
    // type aliases - private to A
    using str = std::string;   
    using strings = std::vector<std::shared_ptr<str>;
    
    public:
       // public interface 
       void funcA( str a); 
       bool funcB( strings strs);    
  }

}
```

Note: that this is not a question about namespace aliases.
I am strictly speaking of type-aliases which will become the parameters to public functions.

Comment: What does "safe for a library" mean?

Comment: I mean is it something that could lead to unknown errors, or name clashes or ambiguous overload calls or ODR violations

Comment: All of these things can of course happen and that you named an alias in a certain way may affect it, but the aliases themselves cause no specific problem.

Comment: Is it better to use fully qualified names 'always' in headers? e.g. ns1::ns2::ns3 etc.
Even for class members?

Comment: No, except to the degree that you need to avoid unqualified lookup rules, you typically qualify a name only as far as necessary to reach it from the current scope. And aliases are there precisely to make writing names more comfortable if necessary. There is no problem using them. They even have the benefit that you can use them to describe the usage of the type in the context of the class by the new name and have it be easily replaceable.

Comment: when an alias is declared or when the compiler encounters one, what happens behind the scenes?